# SOAPUI create generic id instead of wsu id

Tags: xml, soap, soapui, signature

I am trying to send a signed soap request. My request has the signature, body everything looks fine. But the soap body tag is referring to signature as

```
<ds:Signature>
 ..
  <ds:reference URI="#id-asdfas123e"></ds:reference>
</ds:Signature>
...
<soapenv:body wsu:id="id-asdfas123e" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
```

The IdResolver code is looking for id or ID or Id as the attribute but what the IdResolver code recieves is wsu:id which is not going to match with the attributes. So eventually it fails for `ResourceResolverException`.
 Is there a way in SoapUI to generate the ID attribute as just id="id-asdfas123e" instead of wsu:id="..."
I saw link in oracle website that these are 2 options to select is there some similar way to do in SoapUI?
Oracle link : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27515_01/common/tutorials/common_what_must_be_signed.html

Answer (score 1):

This xml fragment:

```xml
<soapenv:body wsu:id="id-asdfas123e" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
```

And this:

```xml
<soapenv:body id="id-asdfas123e" xmlns:="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
```

Are totally equivalent, the difference is that the first one use namespace prefix, and the second one use the namespace as default for `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd`.

Therefore I think that here who is failing is the `IdResolver`, because it's not well implemented if it looks for `id` attribute without checking the namespace...

Despite all this I think that there is no way to tell SOAPUI to use or no the namespace prefix for WSS security elements, so the only thing you can do (if it's not possible to correct IdResolver) is to remove the `wsu` prefix from namespace definition and from id attribute in SOAPUI, manually or trying with a groovy script.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, how to remove it, you mean in the backend code where it is received? I agree IdResolver should first resolve the namespace, but it is not. IdResolver is from <code>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.IdResolver.java</code>. I dont have much control of the backend as well. So I thought it would be easy if soapUI have an option to enable or disable wsu namespace.

Comment: @user2001627 I mean to remove the namespace in soapui, you can do it manually or trying to write a groovy script to remove it for you `:)`